# Copy between Metal textures with different pixel formats

Tags: ios, objective-c, metal

I've experimented with the different `copyFromTexture:...` methods, but it seems they always want the same pixel format between textures. I feel like it should be straightforward to copy from a MTLTexture with a `MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Uint` color format to one with `MTLPixelFormatRGBA16Float`, what am I missing here? Do I really need to use the Accelerate framework or similar to convert the pixel format on the CPU? Hoping for something fast I could do every frame...

My code:

```
[blitCommandEncoder copyFromTexture:tempTexture sourceSlice:0 sourceLevel:0 toTexture:anotherTexture destinationSlice:0 destinationLevel:0 sliceCount:1 levelCount:1];
```

Console errors:

```
-[MTLDebugBlitCommandEncoder internalValidateCopyFromTexture:sourceSlice:sourceLevel:sourceOrigin:sourceSize:toTexture:destinationSlice:destinationLevel:destinationOrigin:options:]:447: failed assertion `[sourceTexture pixelFormat](MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Uint) must equal [destinationTexture pixelFormat](MTLPixelFormatRGBA16Float) '
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either a [metal perfomance shaders](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/image_filters) or custom compute shaders.

> [MPSImageConversion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/mpsimageconversion) - A filter that performs a conversion of color
> space, alpha, or pixel format.
>
> As with all Metal Performance Shaders filters, the conversion filter
> allows for source and destination textures with different pixel
> formats and, in that case, will convert the source texture's format to
> the destination texture's format.

Comment: I wish `MPSImageConversion` supported YCbCr color spaces.